# What's the appropriate process for performing a manual CRL check in a Mule flow?

Tags: mule, certificate-revocation

For specific supplier reasons we need to perform a manual certificate revocation check in code.

The code to perform the check is largely complete, the only part we are needing to do is pull the certificate out of the flow and verify it prior to any message transmission. We are therefore hoping to perform this logic during the SSL handshake (or any point prior to submission where the certificate is accessible).

First of all, does Mule even support this?
We have looked into attaching transformers during the Request (assuming Response will be too late) portions of the HTTPS endpoint but we were unable to retrieve the certificate (currently looking in `PEER_CERTIFICATES`, but this is always `null`).

If it's supported, how should this be done?